# HTML5 localstorage in Blackberry OS7

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a Blackberry app using phonegap and Using HTML5's localstorage feature.In Blackberry OS7 device, the localstorage data don't get cleared even after deleting and reinstalling the app. To clear the localstorage I used, localStorage.clear();, but I don't want to clear the localstorage for second launch of the app. How can I do this?  Regards Ashwini